# Why is the DocuSign API setting wrong values in a pre-populated form on upload?

Tags: docusignapi

I've been able to create an envelope with about 6 pre-populated PDF documents in it, add a recipient, add about 4 signature tabs, and upload the envelope to DocuSign successfully. I've followed their C# example almost line-for-line on this, and it's worked perfectly. I can generate an embedded URL, and sign the document to completion. The only problem, however, is that it's auto-filling in some form values incorrectly. I can't figure out how to tell the API to leave the form as-is, and only collect the signatures.

The documents I'm uploading are standard PDF forms with the data already pre-populated. The data labels on the fields are indeed unique, but are structured similarly. For example, I have several date boxes with three fields each: month, day, year. The months for two date fields could be `SignedDate.MM` and `DateOfBirth.MM`, for example. If I have a value in `DateOfBirth.MM` of `05`, but nothing in `SignedDate.MM`, the API is setting `SignedDate.MM` to `05` on upload, which it should not be doing.

Is there a setting or something I'm doing that could cause this behavior? For the record, if I manually upload the document through their online interface, this problem doesn't happen. I have no templates or custom fields set up in my account. I've also tried setting `TransformPdfFields` to `false` and `TemplateLocked` to `true` on Documents, Signers, and the Envelope. Nothing has worked so far.

Here's how I'm creating the envelope, documents, etc.:

```
// Create the documents
var docs = new List<Document>();
docs.Add(new Document()
{
    DocumentBase64 = "CONTENT_HERE",
    Name = "my-doc",
    FileExtension = "pdf",
    DocumentId = "1"
}); 

// Create the tabs
var signTabs = new List<SignHere>();
signTabs.Add(new SignHere()
{
    RecipientId = "1",
    TabLabel = "Sign Here",
    AnchorString = "<Person.Signature>",
    AnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = "true",
    AnchorMatchWholeWord = "true"
});

// Create the signing information
var signers = new Signer[] {
    new Signer()
    {
        Email = "test@test.com",
        Name = "Test Person",
        ClientUserId = "1000",
        RecipientId = "1",
        RoutingOrder = "1",
        Tabs = new Tabs() { SignHereTabs = signTabs }
    }
};

// Create the recipients
var recipients = new Recipients() { Signers = new List<Signer>(signers) };

// Create the envelope
var envelope = new EnvelopeDefinition()
{
    EmailSubject = "Document Signing",
    Documents = docs,
    Recipients = recipients,
    Status = "sent"
};

return envelope;
```

Any insight into this problem would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DocuSign was able to reproduce the issue on their end, and they submitted a bug report to their developers. They're not sure why it's happening, but they believe it has something to do with a hidden attribute/annotation on the form fields themselves.

In the meantime, I was able to run the PDF through Spire.PDF, search for all the empty form fields, and set their values to an empty string. This seems like it should have no effect (setting an empty value to an empty value), but Spire.PDF must be resetting some attributes/annotations under the covers because this fixes my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your PDF documents have PDF fields in them, then you will need to convert the fields to DocuSign fields.

The main technique is to ask DocuSign to convert them. After the fields are converted, you will need to assign them to one or more of your envelope recipients.

This is because PDF Form fields only know about the form as whole. In contrast, DocuSign fields (also know as tabs) are always associated with specific recipient(s). This enables each recipient to update/sign their own fields. (You can also enable a field to be modified by more than one recipient, but that's a different topic.)

To have the PDF form fields converted to DocuSign fields, check out the [documentation.](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/tabs#tab-placement-method-3-pdf-form-field-transformation)

In summary, you will use composite templates to both indicate that a recipient is the `defaultRecipient` (so they will have the PDF Form Fields assigned to them.) and indicate that each document's PDF Form Fields should be transformed (using the `transformPdfFields` field):

```
{
    "status": "sent",
    "emailSubject": "Transform PDF Fields Example 1",
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [{
            "email": "john@email.com",
            "name": "Jon Dough",
            "recipientId": "1"
        }]
    },
    "compositeTemplates": [{
        "inlineTemplates": [{
            "sequence": "1",
            "recipients": {
                "signers": [{
                    "email": "john@email.com",
                    "name": "Jon Dough",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "defaultRecipient": "true"
                }]
            }
        }],
        "document": {
            "documentId": "1",
            "name": "irs_f4506t.pdf",
            "documentBase64": "<base64 encoded bytes>",
            "transformPdfFields": "true"
        }
    }]
}
```

It is also possible to use the Composite Templates feature to assign some of the PDF Form Fields to recipient 1 and others to recipient 2, as needed.

Comment: I don’t understand how this helps me. I don’t need the fields to be editable any longer. I essentially want to lock the fields so neither DocuSign nor the recipient can edit them, but DocuSign is adding incorrect values for empty fields.

Comment: Hmm try setting `transformPdfFields` to false for the document object. Also, use the logging feature to see what the web tool is doing differently than your app